# How to fix deleted .vagrant directory?

Tags: vagrant

I accidentally deleted the `.vagrant` directory for one of my VMs. Now, when I attempt to use `vagrant ssh`, it fails with:

```
==> vm-name: VM not created. Moving on...
```

The VM *is* created (I can see the provisioning proceeding happily in another terminal window), but I can't get to it.

How do I recreate my `.vagrant` directory, so that I can access this VM?

I don't particularly want to destroy and recreate the VM, because the provisioning step takes a couple of hours.

(Vagrant version 1.9.1, macOS, using Parallels)

Comment: What did you do to accidentally delete it? Have you tried going to `.Trash` location for the volume? I believe the path would be `/volumes/NameOfVolume/.Trash` Then you could use `ls -la` in the terminal to see if it's there.

Comment: `git clean -dffx`. It's toast.

Comment: Oh..... I'm not sure when the `.vagrant` file is made. `vagrant up` would maybe create it again? If you want the file back your best bet would be to use a system recovery tool like a Mac equivalent of Recuva. Time Machine would be a good one if you have a backup, or some method of restoring your files to a time in the recent past.

Comment: Try this:
https://badzilla.co.uk/restoring-accidentally-deleted-vagrant-directory